# Fonts in @react-pdf/pdfkit + react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pdfkit, react-pdf

I ran into the problem that I can't add a font to pdfkit (utf-8) 
**Error: Can't open public/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf in browser build**

I tried plugging in fs-virtual, but that didn't help.

Unfortunately, moving the generation to api is not my option, as I'm working with basic-primitives + react and judging by the documentation I need to make it so that the generation is on the web part.
I need this because out of the box there is no support for the language I need

```
import PDFDocument from '@react-pdf/pdfkit';

export const renderPdf = () => {
  const blobStream = require('blob-stream');

  const doc = new PDFDocument({});
  doc.info['Title'] = 'Org-diagram';

  const stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());
  const legalSize = { width: 612.0, height: 1008.0 };
  const scale = Math.min(legalSize.width / (100 + 100), legalSize.height / (1000 + 100));
  doc.save();
  doc.scale(scale);
  doc.font('public/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf').fontSize(15).text('Привет', 50, 50);

  doc.restore();

  doc.end();

  stream.on('finish', function () {
    const string = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');
    document.getElementById('previewpanel').setAttribute('src', string);
  });
};
```